# Programmatically find changeset from GitHub pull request

Tags: git, github, pull-request

Based on a GitHub pull request, say [this example](https://api.github.com/repos/github/gitignore/pulls/566), one can find the source (head) and target (base) branch.

But, I am interested in obtaining the changeset programmatically.

What is the recommended approach?

P.S: I am looking for changeset between source and target branch.

Comment: By changeset, do you mean the commits? Or a diff between the source and target branches?

Comment: I mean between source and target branches.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the information discussed here can be found in the [git diff](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt-emgitdiffemltoptionsgtltcommitgtltcommitgt--ltpathgt82308203) documentation.

First, get the latest commit SHAs from the pull request, and the target branch. Then you can get the names of the files changed between the two, and even filter based on what [kind of change](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---diff-filterACDMRTUXB82308203) you're looking for.

```sh
#get names (filtered only for modified files)
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=M <source.sha> <target.sha> 

# get changes on a specific file
git diff <source.sha> <target.sha> <filename> 

# get differences on all changes
git diff <source.sha> <target.sha>
```

This will print out the diff between the two, provided you can construct and execute this command with the `base.sha` and `head.sha` supplied from the JSON that the pull request returns. You might want to experiment with git diff flags to see if you can output the information in a specific manner.

Comment: So for that I would need the repo cloned it seems. Also, how can I determine file list in pull request? I only want to run diff for a specific files in changeset so.

Comment: I looked at the thread but I would prefer getting file list first from the pull request first such that if a particular file pattern is not found - git diff will not be needed

Comment: Right, for that you can run the same git diff with the `--name-only` flag.

Comment: After looking, one way I found was looking for "commits_url" in Github payload and then make another API call to get commit sha values which will give file list.

Comment: yes that will give you the information for all commits. It returns an array of commits made towards that pull request. You will need the most recent commit in that list to figure out what is going to be merged

Comment: Hi, I have edited the answer based on these comments. Please let me know if you have any more questions.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Github pull request](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#custom-media-types) documentation, there are Custom media type supported by the APIs.

In order, to get diffs for a given pull request, one can add suffix ".diff" to Pull request url.
For diff, you will need to add below to header.

```
Accept: application/vnd.github.VERSION.diff
```